# Specs not found in using scripts tag in package.json for Protractor

Tags: protractor

In pretest command "tsc" i have used so that file should convert to js. This command changes ts code to js. Now in config js file specs extension remains TS example- file "testspec.ts" not js. extension is not changing. Due to this i am facing specs not found. Extension should also change in configuration.js of specs file.How can i resolve this, so that i just have to give command npm run test and my testcase executes.

Code of package.json

```
{
  "name": "protractortypescriptcucumberframework",

  "version": "1.0.0",

  "description": "cucumberframework",

  "main": "index.js",

  "scripts": {

    "test": "protractor JSFiles/configuration.js",

    "pretest": "tsc",

    "protractor":"./node_modules/protractor/built/cli.js",

    "webdriver-update":"./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update"

  },

  "author": "ak",

  "license": "ISC",

  "dependencies": {

    "protractor": "^7.0.0",

    "typescript": "~3.9.6",

    "jasmine": "~3.5.0",

    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.11",

    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",

    "ts-node": "~8.10.2",

    "@types/node": "~14.0.23"

  }

}
```

Error i face is below after command > npm run test

```
> protractortypescriptcucumberframework@1.0.0 pretest C:\Users\Admin\Eclipse Protractor JavaScript\ProtractorTypeScriptCucumberFramework

> tsc

> protractortypescriptcucumberframework@1.0.0 test C:\Users\Admin\Eclipse Protractor JavaScript\ProtractorTypeScriptCucumberFramework

> protractor JSFiles/configuration.js

[13:49:25] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver

[13:49:25] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49802/devtools/browser/9a9f6b17-da99-4aec-993c-a265017ee716

> protractortypescriptcucumberframework@1.0.0 test C:\Users\Admin\Eclipse Protractor JavaScript\ProtractorTypeScriptCucumberFramework

> protractor JSFiles/configuration.js

[13:49:25] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver

[13:49:25] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49802/devtools/browser/9a9f6b17-da99-4aec-993c-a265017ee716

Started


No specs found

Finished in 0.218 seconds


[13:49:49] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running

[13:49:49] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed
```

Config file code.

import {Config} from "protractor";

// An example configuration file

export let config: Config = {

```
// The address of a running selenium server.

//seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

directConnect:true,

// Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.

capabilities: {

  browserName: 'chrome'

},

// Spec patterns are relative to the configuration file location passed

// to protractor (in this example conf.js).

// They may include glob patterns.

specs: ['testspec.ts'],

// Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.

jasmineNodeOpts: {

  showColors: true, // Use colors in the command line report.

}
```

};

Comment: Can you share your config file for protractor?

Comment: here is config file.

Comment: Did you try changing `specs: [testspec.ts]` to `specs: [testspec.js]` in your protractor config file? Since it's looking for specs relative to the config file (which is in the JSFiles folder), it should only find a .js file and not a .ts file there.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the error.
In config file of ts extension need to pass spec with js extension only. scripts tag will not automatically change spec extension. It has to be passed by user in config ts file.